# Continuous extension of a continuous function $f:A \subseteq [0,1] \rightarrow X$ where $A$ is closed and $X$ is a peano continum

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, connectedness

A peano continuum is a connected, compact and locally connected metric space. This kind of spaces is arc connected and as is stated in the following is uniformly locally arc connected.

The problem is to extend $f$ to a continuous function $F$ defined on all of $[0,1]$. I don't really know how to prove this because I think I'm supposed to use that $X$ is uniformly locally arc connected, that is, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $x,y \in X$ are such that $d(x,y) < \delta$ then there's an arc $A$ that starts in $x$ and ends in $y$ such that $diam(A) < \epsilon$. But I don't know how to use this.

I tried to define manually $F$ over all connected components $(a,b)$ of $[0,1] \setminus A$ by defining $F$ on this component to be the arc from $f(a)$ to $f(b)$, but by doing this I don't know how to prove the continuity of $F$, because the easiest way to do so would be by defining a continuous function all over $\overline{[0,1]\setminus A}$, but this would only be easy if the closure of the union of the disjoint open intervals that make up $X\setminus A$ would be the union of the closure of those intervals, but that doesn't always happen, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\diam}{\text{diam}}$
$\newcommand{\dist}{\text{dist}}$

Let $\delta(\epsilon)$ denote the $\delta$ in your definition of uniform local arc-connectivity.

Now, define $F$ as you propose, to be given on each complementary component $(a,b)$ of $A$ by an arc from $f(a)$ to $f(b)$, parametrized by $[a,b]$, of diameter at most $\delta(\dist(f(a),f(b)))$.  Then continuity on $[0,1]\backslash A$ is immediate.  Moreover, by uniform continuity of $f$ on $A$ we have for each $\epsilon>0$  some $\eta>0$ for which $a,b\in A$ and $|a-b|\leq \eta$ implies $\dist(f(a),f(b))\leq \delta(\frac{\epsilon}{3})$.

To verify continuity at each point $x\in A$, simply check left continuity and right continuity separately.  We show left continuity, with right continuity following from an identical argument.  There are two cases to consider.  The first is that $x$ is the right boundary of a complementary interval $(a,b)=(a,x)$.  In this case, left continuity follows immediately from the definition of $F$ on $[a,b]$ as a parametrized arc.

In the second case, $x$ is not a right boundary of a complementary interval, whereby there are points $x_i<x$ with $x_i\in A$ and $x_i\to x$.  Then for $\epsilon>0$ choose $\eta$ as above, and fix $x_i$ with $|x_i-x|\leq\eta$. Then we have $\diam(F(A\cap [x_i,x]))\leq\delta(\frac{\epsilon}{3})$, and so for each complementary interval $I\subseteq [x_i,x]\backslash A$ we have $\diam(F(I))\leq\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Note that certainly $\delta(\frac{\epsilon}{3})\leq\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. (Even were this not already guaranteed, we could impose that requirement with no problem anyway). Therefore, since the image of every complementary interval's closure intersects $F(A)$, every point in $F([x_i,x])$ lies within distance $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ from a point in $F(A\cap [x_i,x])$, whose diameter is at most $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$, so the total diameter of $F([x_i,x])$ is at most $\epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we have left continuity.